# Xcode and input/output files

Tags: xcode, input

I have to put my input files directly in the root directory for xcode to see them, and the output files are always in the same root directly.

How can I configure xcode to change the input/output directories ?

Comment: Do you mean code file input to Xcode or the input files to the application you are building with Xcode

Comment: input files to the application I'm building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application should never make any assumptions about the current working directory when it is launched. It will be different when launched with Xcode than when launched from a command line or from the Finder or via other means. You need to either use absolute paths for your input/output files (icky, but may be acceptable for "research" type code), or put them in some specific location, or have some other reliable way of defining the location.